# NoSuchMethodError using svnkit to add a file to my repository

Tags: java, svn, svnkit, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to add a file to my repository using svnkit but I get a NoSuchMethodError referencing this line of code:

```
SVNDiffWindow diffWindow = SVNDiffWindowBuilder.createReplacementDiffWindow(deltaLength);
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.diff.SVNDiffInstruction.<init>(IJJ)V
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.diff.SVNDiffWindowBuilder.createReplacementDiffWindow(SVNDiffWindowBuilder.java:529)
at adc.ui.util.SvnTest.testSvnCommit(SvnTest.java:109)
```

And here's all the code:

```
        File file = new File( "c:/development/photolib/discounts/svnTesting/testThisTextCommit1.txt" );
    try {
        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
        String url = "https://subversion.access.dev/svn/sticks/media/trunk/Discounts/PhotoLib/svnTesting";

        SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
        ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor("This is a log message.", new CommitMediator());

        editor.openRoot(-1);
        editor.addFile("testThisTextCommit1.txt", null, -1);
        editor.applyTextDelta("testThisTextCommit1.txt", null);

        long deltaLength = file.length();
        SVNDiffWindow diffWindow = SVNDiffWindowBuilder.createReplacementDiffWindow(deltaLength);
        OutputStream os = editor.textDeltaChunk("testThisTextCommit1.txt", diffWindow);
        os.close();
        editor.textDeltaEnd("testThisTextCommit1.txt");
        editor.closeFile("testThisTextCommit1.txt", null);
        editor.closeEdit();
    }
```

Could it be that I'm using an out of date version? This is the dependency I'm using:

```
<pluginRepository>
  <id>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</id>
  <name>tmatesoft.svnkit svnkit Repository</name>
  <url>http://maven.svnkit.com/maven2/</url>
</pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVNDiffWindowBuilder is no longer in use. The following code should be used in its place:

```
String chksm = deltaGenerator.sendDelta(path, xontentsStream, editor, true); editor.closeFile(path, chksm);
```

Working code:

```
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(svnUrl));
        SVNDeltaGenerator deltaGenerator = new SVNDeltaGenerator();
        ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor("This is a log message.", new CommitMediator());
        editor.openRoot(-1);
        editor.addFile("testThisTextCommit1.txt", null, -1);
        editor.applyTextDelta(svnUrl, null);
        InputStream is = SVNFileUtil.openFileForReading(file);
        String chksm = deltaGenerator.sendDelta(svnUrl, is, editor, true);

        is.close();
        editor.textDeltaEnd("testThisTextCommit1.txt");
        editor.closeFile("testThisTextCommit1.txt", chksm);
        editor.closeEdit();
```